# Smartform error "Flat types may only be referenced using LIKE for table parameters"

Tags: abap, sap-smart-forms

I created a table ZPDETAIL01 in se11 and activated it. 
In smartforms' Form Interface I create a table parameter zdetail in the tables tab, with type assignment as TYPE and associated type as ZPDETAIL01.
When I check it ,an error occurred,"ZPDETAIL01 Flat types may only be referenced using LIKE for table parameters"

Is this  error of my table itself or my parameter setting? Thx.

I changed the type assignment to LIKE and problem solved. But I wonder why in the search help button I can't find the LIKE option, only TYPE and TYPE REF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply a flaw in the UI. If it's allowed then it should be listed as a possible value.

But I guess SAP just didn't care to correct those little things of this obsolete technology (i.e. Smart Forms... now prefer Adobe forms or third-party solutions). Note that the list of values come from the table `RSFBTYPEIN`, and probably `LIKE` was previously defined in this table but as LIKE became obsolete for typing import and export parameters in function modules, SAP probably removed it: majority wins over minority. Just a guess.

If you wish, you may open a ticket at SAP support to make it corrected.

Behaviors in ABAP 7.52 SP01 (tests done with DDIC objects: flat table SCARR, non-flat table SOTR_TEXTU, table type BAPIRETTAB):

```
Typing   Associated type    Button           Error message
------   ----------------   --------------   -------------------------------------------
TYPE     Flat struc/table   Check            SCARR Flat types may only be referenced 
                                             using LIKE for table parameters
TYPE     Flat struc/table   Activate         Only table types may be used as the 
                                             reference type for a table parameter
TYPE     Non-flat str/tab.  Check/Activate   Only table types may be used as the 
                                             reference type for a table parameter
TYPE     Table type         Check/Activate   None
LIKE     Flat struc/table   Check/Activate   None

LIKE     Non-flat str/tab.  Check/Activate   None but short dump at runtime (because of
                                             syntax error in FM: "&1" must be a flat 
                                             structure. Internal tables, strings, references, 
                                             and structures cannot be used as components.)
LIKE     Table type         Check            Type BAPIRETTAB is not allowed in this context
LIKE     Table type         Activate         Tables using LIKE may only reference flat structures
```

As you see, there's a bigger problem than just not displaying LIKE, there's a short dump in one case!

Note that I didn't test TYPE REF TO, but I doubt a TABLES parameter can use it.

Comment: THX. I also tried TYPE REF TO and it report error. If you don't  mind I have another question. what's the difference between import and table tabs? Because I can create parameters in both tabs with table as associated type. only difference is in import I use TYPE and in table I use LIKE.

Comment: The parameters of Smart Forms just mimic the ones in function modules. The TABLES parameters are now obsolete (except in RFC, but that doesn't concern Smart Forms). TABLES parameters declare automatically internal tables, while import parameters depend exclusively on the "associated type" (if it's a Table Type then the parameter is an internal table, otherwise it's not).

Comment: Thx for the explanation. I tried to define an internal table type parameter in importing tab and error occurred when processing. I use code like `Data : result TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF zpack_detail WITH EMPTY KEY. call function fm_name
       exporting  zdetail = dresult`

Comment: What the error says? (if you used a DDIC Table Type `ZTABLETYPE` for typing the Smart Forms import parameter, then in your program simply declare `data dresult type ztabletype` to avoid type mismatch - Maybe it's because of the key, maybe `with default key` instead of `with empty key`)

Comment: The error code is `is only fields of a paticular type can be sepcified under "ZDETAIL".FIeld "DRESULT" specified here has a different filed type however`. and I import the parameter using IMPORTING. when i change the parameter to table and import using TABLES it worked.

Comment: You have a working example in demo Smart Form `SF_EXAMPLE_01` and program of same name, which use 2 Import parameters based on Table Types.